# VHDL inout port set to high impedance

Tags: vhdl

**UPDATE**

I updated the testbench code but now, it seems that databuffer doesn't drive the signals.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
ENTITY databus_buffer_tb IS
END databus_buffer_tb;


ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF databus_buffer_tb IS
  SIGNAL T_Idata:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL T_Odata:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL T_Ctrl:STD_LOGIC:='0';
  COMPONENT databus_buffer IS
      PORT
         (
           --IDATA represent the bus lines that comes from the uC for reading and writing;
           --ODATA represents the bus lines that communicate with the internal bus;
           IDATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):="00000000";
           CTRL:     IN      STD_LOGIC;
           ODATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):="00000000"
     );
   END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
  databuffer:databus_buffer PORT MAP
    (
      IDATA=>T_Idata,
      CTRL=>T_Ctrl,
      ODATA=>T_Odata
      );
  PROCESS
  BEGIN



    T_Idata<="00001111";

    T_Ctrl<='0';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Odata="00001111") REPORT "Expected 00001111" SEVERITY error;

    T_Odata<="11110000";

    T_Ctrl<='1';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Idata="11110000") REPORT "Expected 11110000" SEVERITY error;


    T_Ctrl<='Z';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Idata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Idata" SEVERITY error;
    assert(T_Odata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Odata" SEVERITY error;
    wait;
  END PROCESS;
END dataflow;
```

And [image]

---

I tried to understand how INOUT port should be implemented in VHDL but I failed. 
Here is the code:

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
----------------------------
-- Databus Buffer
----------------------------
ENTITY databus_buffer IS
-- data bus buffer have the next ports:
-- IDATA:        8 bit bus       ->inout
-- CTRL:        1 bit control   ->in
-- ODATA:       8 bit bus       ->inout
    PORT
    (
        --IDATA represent the bus lines that comes from the uC for reading and writing;
        --ODATA represents the bus lines that communicate with the internal bus;
            IDATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
            CTRL:     IN      STD_LOGIC;
            ODATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
        );



END databus_buffer;
ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF databus_buffer IS
-- behaviour of databus buffer;

BEGIN
-- is a 3 state bidirection 8 bit buffer.
-- if CTRL is 1, IDATA=ODATA; reading from counter operation
-- if CTRL is 0, ODATA=IDATA; writing to control word
-- if CTRL is Z, IDATA=Z; this happens when nor read and write are active but
-- cs is active;
-- also, data bus can be in 3rd state if the chip is not selected, this means
-- that CTRL will be Z;


    ODATA<=IDATA WHEN CTRL='0' else "ZZZZZZZZ" WHEN CTRL='Z' else (OTHERS=>'Z');
    IDATA<=ODATA WHEN CTRL='1' else "ZZZZZZZZ" WHEN CTRL='Z' else (OTHERS=>'Z');



END behaviour;
```

This code works when CTRL is 0 or 1. But when I set CTRL to be 'Z', in high impedance, IDATA and ODATA are not set to high impedance.

My testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
ENTITY databus_buffer_tb IS
END databus_buffer_tb;


ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF databus_buffer_tb IS
  SIGNAL T_Idata:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):="00000000";
  SIGNAL T_Odata:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):="00000000";
  SIGNAL T_Ctrl:STD_LOGIC:='0';
  COMPONENT databus_buffer IS
      PORT
         (
           --IDATA represent the bus lines that comes from the uC for reading and writing;
           --ODATA represents the bus lines that communicate with the internal bus;
           IDATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
           CTRL:     IN      STD_LOGIC;
           ODATA:    INOUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
     );
   END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
  databuffer:databus_buffer PORT MAP
    (
      IDATA=>T_Idata,
      CTRL=>T_Ctrl,
      ODATA=>T_Odata
      );
  PROCESS
  BEGIN
    T_Idata<="00000000";
    T_Odata<="00000000";
    T_Ctrl<='0';

    T_Idata<="00001111";
    T_ODATA<="ZZZZZZZZ";
    T_Ctrl<='0';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Odata="00001111") REPORT "Expected 00001111" SEVERITY error;

    T_Odata<="11110000";
    T_IDATA<="ZZZZZZZZ";
    T_Ctrl<='1';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Idata="11110000") REPORT "Expected 11110000" SEVERITY error;

    T_IData<="00000000";
    T_OData<="00000000";    
    T_Ctrl<='Z';
    WAIT FOR 10 ns;
    assert(T_Idata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Idata" SEVERITY error;
    assert(T_Odata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Odata" SEVERITY error;
    wait;
  END PROCESS;
END dataflow;
```

Also, how can be controlled the inout ports in a process, in a sequential way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple drivers for `T_IDATA` and `T_ODATA`. These signals are driven both by the testbench and by the databuffer. The final result is determined by the resolution function of std_logic. In the last (non-working) case, the testbench itself drives `T_IDATA` and `T_ODATA` to low.

Let's take a look on a case which works: (Example taken from the original testbench, this case is broken in the updated testbench because the signal `T_ODATA` has no initialization.)

```
T_Idata<="00001111";
T_ODATA<="ZZZZZZZZ";
T_Ctrl<='0';
WAIT FOR 10 ns;
assert(T_Odata="00001111") REPORT "Expected 00001111" SEVERITY error;
```

Here, the testbench drives `T_ODATA <= "ZZZZZZZZ"` and the data-buffer `T_ODATA <= "00001111"`. This is resolved to "00001111", thus the assert is satisfied.

Now the case which does not work:

```
T_IData<="00000000";
T_OData<="00000000";    
T_Ctrl<='Z';
WAIT FOR 10 ns;
assert(T_Idata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Idata" SEVERITY error;
assert(T_Odata="ZZZZZZZZ") REPORT "Expected Z FOR T_Odata" SEVERITY error;
```

Here, the testbench drives `T_ODATA <= "00000000"` and the data-buffer `T_ODATA <= "ZZZZZZZZ"`. This is resolved to "00000000", thus the assert fails. Same applies to `T_IDATA`.

**EDIT**: In this non-working case, the testbench should also drive

```
T_IData<="ZZZZZZZZ";
T_OData<="ZZZZZZZZ";
```

to get the expected result.

**EDIT 2**: These lines must added to the updated testbench, otherwise the previous assignments from the testbench are used for resolution.

Comment: @23ars Please note, that the check for `CTRL_Z = 'Z'` inside the data-buffer cannot be built in real hardware. It is not needed in your example anway because you assigned the same value in both `else` cases (for each output signal). `ODATA<=IDATA WHEN CTRL='0' else "ZZZZZZZZ";` is sufficient.

Comment: @23ars The updated testbench must drive `T_IData` and `T_OData` to all `z` in the last test case to get the expected result. Otherwise the previous assignments from the testbench are still valid and used for resoultion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!